# I created a normal page, but the page displays as an archive page

Tags: archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have created a normal page called "Clients," which should display the logos of my customers. But the page displays as an archive page. The page I'm talking about is http://zedwrites.com/clients/

Kindly help me to change the archive page to a normal page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a custom post type also called clients which is already using that slug. Try using a different slug/page name or work with the default archive page.

Comment: Seems that way, the body has this class: `post-type-archive-clients`

Comment: Try changing the slug of the page?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what post-type-archive-clients is. But I created a client list from my wp dashboard.

Comment: How do I change the slug of the page?

Comment: Go on the page and under Title, there will be a slug (url) you can change.

Comment: Understood. But I think it's good practice to have your page name match the permalink?

Comment: You are right. This was a quick workabout for your issue.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please tick it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using "Sydney" theme, please follow it's [Sydney - Documentation](https://docs.athemes.com/category/8-sydney). They are using `client` as `custom post type`.

You need to understand the theme's usage, most of the time, follow the documentation theme provides, it will help you understand how it works.